# How do I prevent the onClick of the parent going off when clicking the child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this component code:

```
const myCardItem = ({ item }) => {

    function clickItem(){
        alert('Item clicked');
    }

    function clickMe(){
        alert('Button clicked');
    }

    return (
        <div className="myCardItem" onClick={clickItem}>
            <i className="fa fa-clock-o"/>&nbsp;{item.planDate}
            <br />
            <i className="fa fa-location-arrow"/>&nbsp;{item.destination}
            <br />
            <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={clickMe}>Click Me</Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If I click the button I get first:

[image]

Followed by:

[image]

Which makes sense, because the button is a child under the myCardItem. But that's not what I want. Clicking the `myCardItem` will load a new view, while clicking the button would open a modal dialog. Having both go off would break the page.

> How can I prevent the parent click being called?

It's not as easy as doing a return false in `clickMe()` ...

Comment: `stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` these stop event bubbling and end bubble of events where it is called.

Comment: Presenting your solution with a revised version of OP's code is a way to go.

Comment: yes You are right.